# How to create encryption key

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

I followed all the steps for Commerce Server 2009 R2 Three Tier Installation.

Everything is good, the Commerce server works good, all the .wsp are deployed successfully and the web application is created. I am using a self created certificate.

But when I try to browse the site I get an error like this (Sharepoint Log Viewer):

```
Name=Request (GET:http://wfe1:8000/)

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The encryption key for secureCookieEncryptionKey is required.
 at Microsoft.Commerce.Server.CommerceUserRecognition.Initialize()
 at Microsoft.Commerce.Server.CommerceUserRecognition.GetAnonymousUserId()
 at Microsoft.Commerce.Server.CommerceUserRecognitionModule.GetAnonymousUserId()
 at Microsoft.Commerce.Server.CommerceUserRecognitionModule.OnPostAuthenticateRequest()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Site=/

Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://wfe1:8000/)). Execution Time=20.6327200803454
```

How can i create an encryption key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this was answered over on msdn social
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/commserver2009/thread/c62cf52a-b52f-4eda-9c9c-e4e99321d6fb/